# Line chart alignment with different data sets

Tags: d3.js

I want to generate line chart examples for different data sets on vida.io. I derive mine from the example on github page:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245

When I draw the graph with AAPL price data set, line chart looks good.

http://vida.io/documents/ohwSdN3usxSCWFaS7

But when I upload another data set (Seattle temperature 2012), the line spills over x-axis.

http://vida.io/documents/QZZTrhk7SmfChczYp

Any suggestion on how I can fix the template to make it work with any data set?

Comment: Looks fine here, what exactly do you mean by "spill over"?

Comment: Now that I look at it, December mark is beginning of December. There are data points from Dec 1 to Dec 31. The graph is correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph is actually correct. Thanks to Lars for pointing out. December mark is beginning of December. There are data points from December 1 to 31. So the graph is drawn beyond December mark on x-axis.